# Trouble with Action.AssignToCategory using Python to create Outlook Rules

Tags: python, outlook, categories, comtypes

I have a Python script to create outlook rules based on some details in an Excel spreadsheet (rule name, from address, folder to move to and category).

I've been able to get the `MoveToFolder` action to work, but can't figure out the `AssignToCategory` one.

This is what the data in the excel file looks like. I bring it in as a list of strings (1 string per row) and use split to get the individual values.

[image: Excel File]

Here is the Python script:

```
import comtypes.client as cc
import Read_Excel as xl

# Get details for rules to create from Excel File
rules_to_proces = xl.load_rules(r"C:\Users\myname\Documents\Outlook_Rules.xlsx")

# Create Outlook object
olApp = cc.CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

# Get Outlook collection of rules
olRules = olApp.Session.DefaultStore.GetRules()

# Get Account address
olAccount = olApp.GetNamespace('MAPI').Accounts.Item(1).DisplayName

# For each rule pulled in from the Excel file
for pRule in rules_to_proces:

    # Set the rule name, from email address, folder/s and category based on data pulled in from Excel
    olRuleName = pRule.split(';')[0]
    olRuleAddress = pRule.split(';')[1]
    olRuleFolder = pRule.split(';')[2]
    olRuleCategory = pRule.split(';')[3]

    # Create a new rule in the Outlook rules collection
    olRule = olRules.Create(olRuleName, 0)

    # Set the from condition to the email address and name of the sender and enable the condition
    olFromCondition = olRule.Conditions.From
    olFromCondition.Enabled = True
    olFromCondition.Recipients.Add(olRuleAddress)
    olFromCondition.Recipients.Add(olRuleName)
    olFromCondition.Recipients.ResolveAll

    # Set the root folder for the account
    olRootFolder = olApp.GetNamespace('MAPI').Folders.Item(olAccount)

    # Get a count of how many folders deep the string from Excel file has
    # i.e. Inbox/Folder = 2, Inbox/Folder/Folder = 3 etc.
    olFolderCount = len(olRuleFolder.split('/'))

    # Set destination folder up to 5 folders deep, depending on olFolderCount
    if olFolderCount == 1:
        olDestinationFolder = olRootFolder\
            .Folders[olRuleFolder.split(r'/')[0]]
    elif olFolderCount == 2:
        olDestinationFolder = olRootFolder\
            .Folders[olRuleFolder.split(r'/')[0]]\
            .Folders[olRuleFolder.split(r'/')[1]]
    elif olFolderCount == 3:
        olDestinationFolder = olRootFolder\
            .Folders[olRuleFolder.split(r'/')[0]]\
            .Folders[olRuleFolder.split(r'/')[1]]\
            .Folders[olRuleFolder.split(r'/')[2]]
    elif olFolderCount == 4:
        olDestinationFolder = olRootFolder\
            .Folders[olRuleFolder.split(r'/')[0]]\
            .Folders[olRuleFolder.split(r'/')[1]]\
            .Folders[olRuleFolder.split(r'/')[2]]\
            .Folders[olRuleFolder.split(r'/')[3]]
    elif olFolderCount == 5:
        olDestinationFolder = olRootFolder\
            .Folders[olRuleFolder.split(r'/')[0]]\
            .Folders[olRuleFolder.split(r'/')[1]]\
            .Folders[olRuleFolder.split(r'/')[2]]\
            .Folders[olRuleFolder.split(r'/')[3]]\
            .Folders[olRuleFolder.split(r'/')[4]]
    else:
        print("Folder tree too deep.")

    #  Enable move to folder action, set to enabled and set destination folder
    olMove = olRule.Actions.MoveToFolder
    olMove.__MoveOrCopyRuleAction__com__set_Enabled(True)
    olMove.__MoveOrCopyRuleAction__com__set_Folder(olDestinationFolder)

    # below is what causes the error
    # enable assign to category action, set to enabled and set category to be assigned
    olCategory = olRule.Actions.AssignToCategory
    olCategory.__AssignToCategoryRuleAction__com__set_Enabled(True)
    olCategory.__AssignToCategoryRuleAction__com__set_Categories(olRuleCategory)

# save the rules collection with the new rule added
olRules.Save()
```

Error Output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\myname\PycharmProjects\pythonProject1\Outlook2.py", line 79, in <module>
    olCategory.__AssignToCategoryRuleAction__com__set_Categories(olRuleCategory)
_ctypes.COMError: (-2147352571, 'Type mismatch.', (None, None, None, 0, None))

Process finished with exit code 1

The Action.AssignToCategory.Categories object type is tuple.
```

If I just add tuple, I get a slightly different error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\myname\PycharmProjects\pythonProject1\Outlook2.py", line 79, in <module>
    olCategory.__AssignToCategoryRuleAction__com__set_Categories(tuple(olRuleCategory))
_ctypes.COMError: (-2147024809, 'The parameter is incorrect.', ('Sorry, something went wrong. You may want to try again.', 'Microsoft Outlook', None, 0, None))

Process finished with exit code 1
```

I'm still very new to python so this is really melting my brain. Any help that can be offered would be greatly appreciated?

I've tried as many different versions as I can think of/find online such as:

```
olCategory.__AssignToCategoryRuleAction__com__set_Categories(**[**olRuleCategory**]**)

olCategory.Categories = olRuleCategory

olCategory.Categories = **[**olRuleCategory**]**

olRuleCategory = tuple(olRuleCategory)
```

The way below results in the code executing without error, but there is nothing in the rule about the category.

```
olCategory.__AssignToCategoryRuleAction__com__set_Enabled = True
olCategory.__AssignToCategoryRuleAction__com__set_Categories = olRuleCategory
```

Comment: I can't find a solution to this so I'm just going to try and create a PowerShell function to call from Python. If anyone does come up with a Python only solution, please still post it.